# How to remove a blank line at the end of a text file after deleting a line?

Tags: vb.net, text-files, line, streamreader, streamwriter

I borrowed four lines of code from Stack Overflow, regarding removing a specific line from my text file in vb.net. Here they are:

```
 Dim delLine As Integer = 4
 Dim lines As List (Of String) = File.ReadAllLines ("c:\essai.librarie", Encoding.UTF8).ToList()
 lines.RemoveAt(delLine - 1)
 File.WriteAllLines("c:\outfile.librairie", lines, Encoding.UTF8)
```

It works fine but after deleting my line 4, I have an empty line in the last position of the file with the number 11! (see screenshot).

How to avoid this blank line?

[image]

Comment: After the read, before the delete, what is the count of lines?

Comment: 11 lines, before deleting 1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[File.WriteAllLines()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines) add a line terminator - defined by the `protected` [CoreNewLine](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/textwriter.cs,101) Field in the base class, TextWriter, and returned by the `TextWriter.NewLine` virtual property - to each line it writes, including the last.

You have different method to remove this terminator:

```
Imports System.IO

Dim sourcePath = Path.Combine([Source Path], "SomeFile.txt")
Dim destinationPath = Path.Combine([Dstination Path], "SomeOtherFile.txt")
Dim lineToDelete As Integer = 3

Dim lines As List(Of String) = File.ReadAllLines(sourcePath, Encoding.UTF8).ToList()
lines.RemoveAt(lineToDelete - 1)
```

▶ Simplified method, using [File.WriteAllText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext) and rebuilding the Lines with [String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join):

```
File.WriteAllText(destinationPath, String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines), Encoding.UTF8)
```

`String.Join()` doesn't add the separator to the last element in the array.

▶ Using a [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter), looping the lines in the array to the one before the last, then change the line terminator, setting the [TextWriter.NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.textwriter.newline) property to a null String (not a null Char):

```
Using stream As New StreamWriter(destinationPath, False, Encoding.UTF8)
    Dim index As Integer = 0
    For index = 0 To lines.Count - 2
        stream.WriteLine(lines(index))
    Next
    stream.NewLine = String.Empty
    ' index is set to the closure, lines.Count - 1
    stream.WriteLine(lines(index))
End Using
```

▶ With `File.WriteAllLines()` - which will add the `NewLine` chars to the last line - then use a [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream) to remove the trailing chars by setting the length of the File, calling [FileStream.SetLength()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.setlength):

```
[Stream].Length = [Stream].Length - [Line terminator].Length`
```

Setting the [Stream.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream) to a lower value truncates the file.

```
File.WriteAllLines(destinationPath, lines, Encoding.UTF8)
Using fStream As New FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
    fStream.SetLength(fStream.Length - Environment.NewLine.Length)
End Using
```

▶ Using a `FileStream`, to write the bytes returned by [Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getbytes), adding a line terminator to all lines except the last one:

```
Using fStream As New FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
    Dim lastLine = lines.Count - 1
    For index As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
        Dim line As String = lines(index) & If(index <> lastLine, Environment.NewLine, "")
        Dim bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line)
        fStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    Next
End Using
```

And many more...

As a note, you could simply ignore it, since when you read it back:

```
 lines = File.ReadAllLines(destinationPath, Encoding.UTF8).ToList()
```

You won't find an empty line in the collection. But, of course, this depends on the specific use-case (what these files are for).